# Keeping defines in sync between Erlang and C

Tags: c, erlang, c-preprocessor

From http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/driver.html:

```
/* Keep the following definitions in alignment with the
 * defines in erl_pq_sync.erl
 */
#define DRV_CONNECT             'C'
#define DRV_DISCONNECT          'D'
#define DRV_SELECT              'S'
```

Is there any simple way to share the values of macros between Erlang and C sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing about Erlang, but presumably you can't just create a .h file with just the required defines in and #include it (or equivalent) in both places.

Asuming you can't do this, I would look at auto generating a file for one from the other.

EDIT: Having just looked at the Erlang docs, the format is very similar but not quite the same.

Erlang needs `-define(Const, Replacement)`

C needs `#define const replacement`

So I would write a single text file which contained the Erlang syntax (for just these definitions) and then as a pre-build step in my C build I would do something along the lines of

```
sed s/-define/#define/g 
sed s/[\(\),]//g
```

on a temporary copy of that file, which I would then `#include` in my C source.

Comment: Note that this solution won't work as soon as your macro definition uses another macro.

Comment: @Zed: Indeed, or with any parameterised (function-like) macros. But the examples in the original are very simple and should be OK.

Comment: Yes, the ones I need are that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You may (try to) use C preprocessor of gcc in erlang, as gcc have options:

- `-E` stop after preprocessing stage
- `-x language` (you may set one which gives correct output)
- `-P` inhibit output of `#line`
- `-C` keep comments (do not remove /* */ and // )

Answer (score 1):

One very dynamic way is to keep a table in C wich can easily generated by macros using # that have `char *name` -> values.

Then use this to send erlang a table at the beginning.

```
#define DRV_CONNECT             'C'
#define DRV_DISCONNECT          'D'
#define DRV_SELECT              'S'

#define ENTRY(X) {#X, X}

struct table_entry
{
    const char *name;
    int value
};

struct table_entry table[] =
{
   ENTRY(DVR_CONNECT),
   ENTRY(DRV_DISCONNECT),
   ENTRY(DRV_SELECT)
};
```

Use this table to send it at the beginning to erlang, decode it there into a tuple list and use this to look up.